# How to load third party non-secure images in cordova webview?

Tags: android, image, cordova, webview

I am trying to load an image from another website in cordova webview, and I get the following error

*Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.website.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.image-site.com/image.JPG'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

How to resolve this?

Comment: Just change your request to `https://www.image-site.com/image.JPG`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution; the idea is to use the `MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` of android in the inappbrowser.
You must edit the file `platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/InAppBrowser.java`

and add next to the `WebSettings settings = inAppWebView.getSettings();` line:

```
settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

It's not a good solution, because you are editing the src of the plugin and if you update it, you will lose the changes... but it works for me ;)

Comment: The only solution that actually worked. In my case file was under platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java